# How to extract a single file from a .rar in bash

Tags: bash, shell

Assume we have a `archive.rar` that contains files `file1.csv` and `file2.csv`.

`unrar x archive.rar .` extracts the whole `archive.rar`.

Is it possible to extract `file1.csv` only using bash and how?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Just specify the files you want to extract at the end of the command line.

```
unrar x archive.rar file1 file2 path/to/file3
```

If you type `man unrar` you should get the reference for yourself.  It should look [like this](https://linux.die.net/man/1/unrar)

Comment: Yes, I should have. Thanks anyway.